# Is any way to store Prometheus Data to External Database like mysql or postgreSQL

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, prometheus, prometheus-operator

Currently I am working with the Prometheus and getting a good result, I difficulty I am facing is that if the service restart my whole old data will lose. Is there any way to permanently store the Prometheus data in databases like mysql or PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 4):

You can't write Prometheus data directly to a relational db (or any db for that matter). You have two choices:

1. mount an external disk on your machine and configure Prometheus to write the data to whatever that mount location was
2. Write a tiny web script which translates the Prometheus export format to whatever storage format you want. Then configure Prometheus to send data to the web script.

Information can be found on the [Prometheus docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/).

Comment: A great news is that now we can store Prometheus data to PostgreSQL using the following https://github.com/timescale/pg_Prometheus and can use timescale-db with PostgreSQL as other medium

Comment: May be you forgot to mention about [existent adapters](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/#remote-storage-integrations) ? And yes, now [PostgreSQL adapter](https://github.com/timescale/prometheus-postgresql-adapter) is ready

Answer (score 4):

### Now PostgreSQL support for Prometheus here

https://blog.timescale.com/prometheus-ha-postgresql-8de68d19b6f5

Answer (score 3):

Traditiomal databases like MySQL and PostgreSQL aren't optimized for time series data which is collected by Prometheus. There are better solutions exist, which require less storage space and work faster with both inserts and selects.

Prometheus supports [remote storage](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/integrations/#remote-endpoints-and-storage). When enabled, it stores all the new data in both local storage and remote strorage. There are multiple choices exist for the remote storage db with various tradeoffs. I'd recommend trying [VictoriaMetrics](https://medium.com/devopslinks/victoriametrics-creating-the-best-remote-storage-for-prometheus-5d92d66787ac). It natively supports Prometheus' query language - PromQL, so may be easily used as Prometheus datasource in Grafana.

Comment: A great news is that now we can store Prometheus data to PostgreSQL using the following https://github.com/timescale/pg_Prometheus and can use timescale-db with PostgreSQL as other medium

Answer (score 1):

InfluxDB would be another option:

https://www.influxdata.com/blog/influxdb-now-supports-prometheus-remote-read-write-natively/

Just configure the remote_write and remote_read in your Prometheus config and you are ready to go:

```
remote_write:
  - url: 'http://{YOUR_INFLUX-DB}:{YOUR_INFLUX-DB_PORT}/api/v1/prom/write?db=metrics'
remote_read:
  - url: 'http://{YOUR_INFLUX-DB}:{YOUR_INFLUX-DB_PORT}/api/v1/prom/read?db=metrics'
```